# cyclic includes, how can I resolve this without changing class hierarchy

Tags: c++, class, include

```
            Animal
               |
           Mammal
               / \
      TwoLegged - FourLegged
         /           \
        Human      Lion
```

I have this class hierarchy, each class defined in it's own header.  Now when I include both
Human.h and Lion.h in the same place, I get a Mammal redefinition error.

```
 error C2011: 'Mammal' : 'class' type redefinition
```

This because Mammal.h is included in both TwoLegged and OneLegged classes.

I'm not sure however, how I could resolve this cyclic dependency in headers, as I cannot change the class hierarchy.

Anybody care to assist?

EDIT:

Mammal header

```
#ifndef MAMMAL_H
#define MAMNAL_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Animal.h"

class Mammal : public Animal
{
public:
    Mammal::Mammal();
    virtual Mammal::~Mammal();

    std::string mammal_name();
    int mammal_age();
    int mammal_expectedlifedays();
    bool mammal_hunter();
    int mammal_power();
    int mammal_birthrate();
    bool mammal_alive();

protected:
    Mammal::Mammal(const std::string& mname, int mexpectedlifedays, int mage, bool mhunter, int mpower, int mbirthrate, bool malive) : Animal(mname, mexpectedlifedays, mage,mhunter,  mpower, mbirthrate, malive)
    {}
private:
};

#endif
```

The errors given by the compiler:

```
error C2011: 'Mammal' : 'class' type redefinition
see declaration of 'Mammal'

error C2504: 'Mammal' : base class undefined
error C2614: 'TwoLegged' : illegal member initialization: 'Mammal' is not a base or member
```

Note: It's not homework, else I would have tagged it as such.

Comment: Do you have compile guards on your header file? #ifndef /#def/ #endif

Comment: are you using include guards?

Comment: @John: Yes I have those compile guards.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: @Tony: There must be something wrong with your include guards in `Mammal.h` or you are actually re-defining `class Mammal` somewhere!  The way you describe your problem, there is no cyclic include (e.g. this would be the case if `Mammal.h` included `Lion.h`).

Comment: Explain why you think this is cyclic dependency: I can't see anything that indicates such in the question.

Comment: @Mark: I think because when I include lion.h and human.h, I indirectly include Mammal.h both times. No?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your include guards. They should prevent the redefinition. Post Mammal.h.

Comment: @Tony: This is not a problem as long as you have include guards (this is exactly what they are for).  And it has nothing to do with cycles since `Mammal` is independent of `Lion` and `Human`.

Comment: BTW: Why are you using `Mammal::` to declare your constructors and destructors inside the class? `Mammal()` and `virtual ~Mammal()` will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use include guards. The typical form is:

```
#ifndef NAME_OF_HEADER_H
#define NAME_OF_HEADER_H

// Rest of header code here.

#endif
```

Since `#include` in C++ just does a copy-paste of the text in the current file if the same header gets included twice that text will result in duplicate class definitions. What the include guard does is prevent the multiple inclusion of the same header.

EDIT: The problem is that you check for definition of `MAMMAL_H` and then define `MAMNAL_H` (note the `N` in the defined version). I *always* copy-paste to generate my include guards for precisely this reason.

Comment: @Tony The Tiger: Are you sure or can you recheck if they are in place for all the files and correctly ofcourse!

Comment: @Tony The Tiger In that case I think we need to see a minimal example that exhibits the problem for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
#pragma once
```

Add that at the very top of all your header files.

However, keep in mind that even though it is very well supported by compilers, it's not a standard.

Comment: Better use  #ifndef /#def/ #endif!

Comment: Not so well supported. GCC is known not to have it.

Comment: Absolutely, you'd definitely have to check against the compiler you're using. But if your compiler supports it, then it's much cleaner and less error prone than include guards.

Comment: @rodrigo it's been supported since gcc 3.4. See http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.html

Comment: Guys, this discussion is off-topic.  It is likely that the OP forgot/mistyped include guards (regardless which kind), and this answer is only partially helping.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot include guards. Use  #ifndef /#ifdef/ #endif as John suggested.

Comment: -1 for just guessing and then just referring to someone else's answer.  This answer adds nothing to those already given.

Comment: That's fair! Wasn't intended that way. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef MAMMAL_H
#define MAMMAL_H



... definition of mammal


#endif
```